# How to iterate twice over a list with different conditions?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a for loop as such:

```
    for category in enums.Category:
        category_name = str(category.name)
        internal_code = category.internal_code

        if category_name in labels and not category.is_temporary_code:
            field_label = labels[category_name]
            self.fields[internal_code] = forms.BooleanField(label=field_label, required=False)

        elif category_name in labels and category.is_temporary_code:
            field_label = labels[category_name]
            exp_date_label = labels[category_name] + " end date"
            self.fields[internal_code] = forms.BooleanField(label=field_label, required=False)
            self.fields[internal_code + "_end_date"] = forms.DateField(
                label=exp_date_label, required=False
            )
```

However, this loops through the enums Category instances and produces the result (the form field) in the order of the instances. How could I write this loop so that each instance which falls into the first 'if' condition sets its form field FIRST, and then the loop reruns to set the form fields for the second set of instances (from the elif statement) AFTER?

Comment: Create two lists, one for the first items and one for the second items. In the if/elif you just add the items to one of those lists. After the for loop you loop the items of the both lists and add then to the form.

Comment: Alternative are two for loops together with a list comprehension that performs the if/elif separation. I'm on the phone, otherwise I would provide some code...

Answer (score 1):

You could just have two explicit loops. In this case, your `if` and `elif` conditions are already mutually exclusive, so there is no need in the second case to do `if (condition2) and not (condition1):`, just `if (condition2):` will suffice. 
 There is a small amount of repeated code here as a consequence, but probably not enough to worry about.

(I've moved the assignment of `internal_code` inside the `if` blocks, because it is not required to evaluate the condition.)

```
    for category in enums.Category:
        category_name = str(category.name)
        if category_name in labels and not category.is_temporary_code:
            internal_code = category.internal_code
            field_label = labels[category_name]
            self.fields[internal_code] = forms.BooleanField(label=field_label, required=False)

    for category in enums.Category:
        category_name = str(category.name)
        if category_name in labels and category.is_temporary_code:
            internal_code = category.internal_code
            field_label = labels[category_name]
            exp_date_label = labels[category_name] + " end date"
            self.fields[internal_code] = forms.BooleanField(label=field_label, required=False)
            self.fields[internal_code + "_end_date"] = forms.DateField(
                label=exp_date_label, required=False
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to duplicate code. The second-easiest way would be to run the entire for loop inside
    for run in (1,2):
and just check "run" inside your conditionals.

As an aside, you could avoid having to do an elif with a duplicated conditional there if you had

```
if not category_name in labels:
    continue
if category.is_temporary_code:
    <code>
else:
    <code>
```